# Conditional stylesheet in .vue component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working with vue component (cli .vue)

I need to have my stylesheet appear only if certain boolean is true/false.
Simplest explanation would be something like :
When **myVar==false**, component is not loading styles.

```
<style v-if="myVar" lang="scss"> @import 'mystyles.css' </style>
```

I know it is impossible in that way, but how I'm able to do 'similar' thing?

I need to load my styles in vue if user want to use default Styles, if not I need to prevent them from being loaded.

My component is used not once but many times in page, but that condition of using/not using default css need to be apply by all components as well, so no problem here.

Any ideas?
Thanks for help or any ideas in advance :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using SCSS, you can wrap that CSS in a class, something like this:

```
<style lang="scss">

.conditional-class {
    @import 'stylesheet.scss';
}

</style>
```

And then use a Vue class binding for that class:

```
<div :class="{ conditional-class: true }">
    ...
</div>
```

This way the CSS won't apply unless the class is active on that element. If you want the styles to apply all over the app, then put that class on the app root element.

Comment: I thought about something like that.
But that renders into two separates <style> tags

<styles>
.conditional-class{}
</styles>
<styles>
here goes stylesheet.css
</styles>

Comment: Ok. Just needed to change css into scss file, and it works fine! 
Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Does it have to be scss? I'm using vue-style-loader and I'm trying to load some css from node_modules and I can't change the extensions.

Comment: The imported style sheet file should not have to be CSS. But CSS doesn't allow importing within blocks, only at the top level.

Comment: doesnt seem to work for css that should affect the whole page. Its kind of strange.