# How to add if in style tag in component of vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to access data from `...mapGetters` in `style` tag but it returns an error. I can only access the data in other html tags. Please see my code below.

**Error**

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'authenticated&lang=css&'

**My code**

```
<script>
    import Navbar from '@/components/partials/Navbar.vue'
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        components: {
            Navbar
        },

        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                authenticated: 'auth/authenticated',
                user: 'auth/user'
            })
        }
    }
</script>
<style v-if="!authenticated">
    @import '../assets/css/landing-page.css';
</style>
```

Comment: You cant use v-if directive on <style> tag.

Comment: @BallonUra Okay, how can I only import the css when user is not authenticated?

Comment: Try look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703038/is-it-possible-to-import-css-file-conditionally-in-vue-js

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893611/conditional-stylesheet-in-vue-component/47893705

Comment: I suggest you put your css file into new component that only shown when user authenticated

Comment: @BallonUra I think it's not a good practice to put css file to components. that would be messy

Comment: No put only css, move all html+css into component that need to be toggled when user is auth.

Comment: @MajedBadawi what if the style is for the `body` tag? Like `body{ background: 'black'; }`

Comment: So it better to bind style to the body and use store to determine auth.

Comment: @BallonUra can you please add an example. sorry Im new to vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225640/discussion-between-ballon-ura-and-jonjie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate to new .vue sfc, so the css will load only when the component render `app.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <LoggedIn v-if="authenticated" />
    <SignUp v-else />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LoggedIn from "@/components/LoggedIn.vue";
import SignUp from "@/components/SignUp.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    LoggedIn,
    SignUp,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      authenticated: true,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

And then in your `SignUp.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>Hello from signup</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
@import "../assets/landing-page.css";
</style>
```